# A big list of examples that a power of a prime ideal is not primary in an algebra of finite type over a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, big-list

Let $k$ be a field.
Let $A$ be an integral domain which is a $k$-algebra of finite type.
I would like to know examples that a power of prime ideal of $A$ is not primary.
The more example, the better. In other words, I'm asking a big list of such examples.

Comment: You can use $k[x,y,z]/(x^2 -yz)$ with $p^2$ where $p = (x,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = k[X, Y, Z]/(XY - Z^2)$, where $k[X, Y, Z]$  is a polynomial ring over a field $k$.
Let $x, y, z$ be the image of $X, Y, Z$ respectively by the canonical homomorphism $\phi\colon k[X, Y, Z] \rightarrow A$.
Then $P = (x, z)$ is a prime ideal by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750237/is-this-ideal-prime).
We claim $P^2$ is not primary.
Suppose otherwise.
Since $xy = z^2 \in P^2$, $x \in P^2$ or $y^n \in P^2$ for some $n \ge 1$.
Thus $X \in (X^2, XZ, Z^2, XY - Z^2)$ or $Y^n \in (X^2, XZ, Z^2, XY - Z^2)$.
However, clearly this is not the case.